# How to determine if my phone supports AndroidOne?

Tags: htc, android-one

The HTC U11 Life got my attention when I saw **androidone** printed on its back. Now I got one, but this one doesn't have the **androidone** print on its back. Are there two versions of the phone, one to support **androidone** and another that doesn't?

Is there a setting I can check that would clearly tell me whether my phone supports **androidone** or not?

It came with Android 8.0.0 and it says there are no Software updates available...

**Update:** According to the HTC website there are indeed two versions of the phone: one such and another with a (T-Mobile) suffix. Upon booting the phone there is a T-Mobile screen, thus it looks like I’ve got the T-Mobile version. The question remains though: is this version of the phone not part of the android one program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is indeed a variant of the HTC U11 Life that does not have the Android One branding:

> [the American variant of the same phone does not have the Android One branding](https://www.xda-developers.com/tmobile-htc-u11-life-android-oreo-update/)

The answer to my question should therefore be: if it isn't labeled **androidone** on the rear, it's not in the Android One program.

I will generously assume that the vendor, who marketed the phone with Android One, was also confused by the HTC marketing strategy for this phone. They can take it back though.

Answer (score 2):

This [article](https://www.pocket-lint.com/phones/news/android/129577-what-is-android-one) states that:

> Android One is a Google-devised programme for hardware manufacturers making smartphones. Being part of Android One - and labelled as such on the rear of the phone - brings with it a guarantee that it's a solid and stable version of Android that's not loaded with other apps, services and bloatware.
>   Essentially, it's a stock Android experience.

Your device is an Android One as shown [here](https://www.pocket-lint.com/phones/reviews/htc/142742-htc-u11-life-review-the-ups-and-downs-of-life), [here](https://www.androidauthority.com/htc-u11-life-specs-810272/) and [here](https://gsmarena.com/htc_u11_life-8885.php).

> With Android One, your device will receive up to two years of upgrades to the latest version of Android.

In North America, it was [released](https://www.androidauthority.com/htc-u11-life-specs-810272/) with Android 7.1. It came already [installed](https://gsmarena.com/htc_u11_life-8885.php) with Android 8 in some parts of the world of the world and is [upgradable](https://gsmarena.com/htc_u11_life-8885.php) to Android 9.

> Is there a setting I can check that would clearly tell me whether my phone supports androidone or not?

There is no such setting.

Comment: @MorrisonChang A [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_One#2017) of Android One devices (Wikipedia providing a better list than Google; this world is coming to its end :)). Also an old [article](https://www.xda-developers.com/best-android-one/) for XDA Developers. Bare in mind that Android One is just a program not the software. So the device will still be Android 7, 8, 9 and 10 but with no bloatwares from manufacturers.

Comment: I want to stress again, that my phone does not have the android one label on its rear. Is it possible there is a version of the HTC U11 Life that is not part of the android one program?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I deleted my comment when I checked  archive.org for https://web.archive.org/web/20180124095614/https://www.android.com/one/ and found HTC U11 Life as part of the program.